# $\frac{3}{b+c+d}+ \frac{3}{c+d+a}+\frac{3}{d+a+b}+\frac{3}{a+b+c} \ge \frac{16}{a+b+c+d}$ for $a,b,c,d>0$

Tags: inequality, symmetric-polynomials

Prove that
$$\frac{3}{b+c+d}+ \frac{3}{c+d+a}+\frac{3}{d+a+b}+\frac{3}{a+b+c}
 \ge \frac{16}{a+b+c+d}$$
if $a,b,c,d>0$.

#### My attempt:

I've put this in the answers.

See also comments under [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4529088/please-solve-this-inequality-i-couldnt-understand-it?noredirect=1#comment9519011_4529088).

Comment: I see that the other question recently was a duplicate but closed as not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### My attempt:

Let p=a+b+c+d then
$$
\frac{1}{b+c+d}+ \frac{1}{c+d+a}+\frac{1}{d+a+b}+\frac{1}{a+b+c}\equiv\\{1\over p-a}+{1\over p-b}+{1\over p-c}+{1\over p-d}
$$
By the AM-GM inequality,
$$
{1\over p-a}+{1\over p-b}+{1\over p-c}+{1\over p-d} \geq4\sqrt[4]{1\over(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)(p-c)}.
$$
Also by AM-GM inequality,
$$
\sqrt[4]{(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)(p-c)}\leq\frac14 \left((p-a)+(p-b)+(p-c)+(p-d)\right)\\
=\frac14(4p-p)=\frac34p\\
$$
so
$$
{1\over p-a}+{1\over p-b}+{1\over p-c}+{1\over p-d} \geq {16\over 3p}
$$

Comment: I think it would be much better to use the AM-HM inequality to omit the intermediate process.

Comment: You can add a better answer if you like.

Comment: But question is closed :(

Comment: Sorry I thought when it was closed as a duplicate it was a mistake and it would be reopened but it actually was a duplicate. I tried searching for this equation on the approach0 but the moderator tried harder and typed it in lots of different ways and found the duplicate. Anyway this solution and question can stay here and people can add answers at the duplicate question.